# Using Google Spreadsheet to Update Fusion Table

Tags: javascript, google-fusion-tables

I am having an issue with code I am running in a spreadsheet that updates a fusion table. I run the following code (with the fusion table ID omitted for privacy).

```
 function updateFusion() {

    var tableIDFusion = '##############################'
    var email = UserProperties.getProperty('email'); 
    var password = UserProperties.getProperty('password');     
      if (email === null || password === null) {
        email = Browser.inputBox('Enter email');
        password = Browser.inputBox('Enter password'); 
        UserProperties.setProperty('email',email); 'email'
        UserProperties.setProperty('password', password); 
      }
      var authToken = getGAauthenticationToken(email,password); 
      deleteData(authToken, tableIDFusion); 
      updateData(authToken, tableIDFusion); 
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast(Logger.getLog(), "Fusion Tables Update", 10) 
    }

    //Google Authentication API this is taken directly from the google fusion api website
    function getGAauthenticationToken(email, password) {
      password = encodeURIComponent(password);
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin", {
          method: "post",
          payload: "accountType=GOOGLE&Email=" + email + "&Passwd=" + password + "&service=fusiontables&Source=testing"});
      var responseStr = response.getContentText();
      responseStr = responseStr.slice(responseStr.search("Auth=") + 5, responseStr.length);
      responseStr = responseStr.replace(/\n/g, "");
      return responseStr;
    }
```

I continue to get the error: 
Request failed for https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin returned code 403. Server response: Error=BadAuthentication (line 97)

I understand coding but not much about servers and the way programs interact with each other and the code for my Formula Team's website has been passed to me and this is all a bit over my head and I am not sure what to do.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I've been using this [version](https://gist.github.com/3013360) of a similar script. [John McGrath](https://github.com/jomcgrath2/Update-Fusion) via the Google Fusion Tables group brought it all together to create a manual "sync" between a Google spreadsheet and a Google Fusion Table.

I'm guessing they are similar, but perhaps you are missing some aspects?

I've modified the script a bit for my needs and have added use of an [API key](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/migration_guide#ownClient) and the [new Fusion Tables API endpoint](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/migration_guide) as the original version used the SQL API endpoint, which is being phased out.

To use, simply add your Fusion Table's encrypted table ID to the top of the script...

```
// Add the encrypted table ID of the fusion table here
var tableIDFusion = '17xnxY......';
```

And add your [api key](https://code.google.com/apis/console/)...

```
// key needed for fusion tables api
var fusionTablesAPIKey = '17xnxY......';
```

Comment: I actually just met John, he and I have class together and the code I am working with was his.  We sat down and went through the migration stuff but I am still having the same problem. The error I get is happening in the getGAauthenticationToken function under the var response, well before the queryFusionTables function is called.

Also, the tableICFusion and fusionTablesAPIKey are supposed to be different, correct?

Comment: My utmost apologies for such a late response.

Yes, the fusion table ID and the API key are different. You need to get the API key from the API console here: https://code.google.com/apis/console/

Are you using a personal account for the spreadsheet?
Are the columns in the spreadsheet exactly the same and in the same order in the Fusion Table?