# Update Fusion Table From

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-fusion-tables

**Hi Experts,**

I was trying to update fusion table from google spreadsheet. I tried with the codes available in Google's documentation pages and some others also but seems to be broken.
Treads that I read
[Thread 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14311840/using-google-spreadsheet-to-update-fusion-table),,,
[Thread 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7082611/google-apps-script-update-fusion-table-from-spreadsheet-script)
Code that I tried:
[Code 1](https://github.com/jomcgrath2/Update-Fusion/blob/master/Multiple_Sheets.txt)

Every time am getting
**Request failed for https://www.google.com/accounts/Client Login returned code 403**

Please tell me how to update fusion table from google spreadsheet.

Thanks a lot,
Anees Hameed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After repeated trails I was able to create code which read data from fusion table and write to logger console:

```
function GetData()
{
 var FUSION_URL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?';
 var APIkey = 'key=AIzaSyDdZu1nYAxFa2Wm5DTVYwlAejxET5Wb8XE';
 var query = 'sql=SELECT * FROM 1k6N_-P-wZ2ZMh8B_2Doym5oLsAJXdXHAqZO_H0I WHERE Ratings=7';
 var options =
   {
    method : 'get',
   };
 var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(FUSION_URL+"+query+"&"+APIkey, options);
 Logger.log(response );
 }
```

And then I tried to write data to sql tables using 'post' method, but it is not working.

```
function WriteData()
{
var FUSION_URL = 'https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?';
var APIkey = 'key=AIzaSyDdZu1nYAxFa2Wm5DTVYwlAejxET5Wb8XE';
var query = 'sql=DELETE FROM 1k6N_-P-wZ2ZMh8B_2Doym5oLsAJXdXHAqZO_H0I WHERE Ratings=7';  
 var options =
   {
     method : 'post',
     payload : query,
     headers : {
                key: APIkey
               },
   };
var responce = UrlFetchApp.fetch(FUSION_URL, options); 
Logger.log(responce); 
}
```